# Vaadin Audio seek position

Tags: audio, vaadin

I would like some how to seek position of Audio component in Vaadin, or to read current time from Audio player. Is this possible to do somehow?

Answer (score 0):

These features are not included in Audio component. But luckily there is add-on, more sophisticated audio player, which has the features you are looking for.

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/audiovideo

For even more complex use cases of multiple audio streams there exists also

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/audioplayer-add-on