# Vaadin7 Video component won't allow people to drag to later point in video

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I am showing the video controls, using `video.setShowControls(true);`, but the user cannot drag it to a later time in the video.  They can pause it just fine, they just cannot drag it to a later time.  It ignores your "dragging".  The videos, when I bring them up outside of my application, allows me to do this just fine.  Here is an image showing what I am trying to drag:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vaadin frameworks resource serving for Video and Audio components do not support so called range requests out of the box. Thus dragging play position beyond fetched data wont work.

There are improved versions of the components available in the Directory for Vaadin 8, but unfortunately this add-on has not been backported to Vaadin 7.

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/audiovideo

There is similar question about Audio here: [Vaadin Audio seek position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49491370/vaadin-audio-seek-position)

Answer (score 2):

Seeking by dragging may work if the video file is hosted on an external server (depending on the specifics of that server), but not if it's served through Vaadin as e.g. a `StreamResource`.

Comment: So, in theory, a Youtube video inside a BrowserFrame would probably allow such fine-tuned control.  Heck, if my videos were externally accessible (outside of the Vaadin application), that might work as well.  I believe this is what you are getting at.

Comment: The limitation is indeed with how the bytes of the video file are served and not with the component used to show those bytes as a video in the browser. Vaadin's `Video` component can support seeking when used with an `ExternalResource`(as long as that resource is served from a server that supports range requests), but Vaadin's `StreamResource` doesn't serve bytes in a way that supports seeking.